# Fast single precision reciprocal square root in C++ on very low precision

Tags: c++, performance, x86, sqrt

I have a line in C++

```
c[i] = sqrtf(a[i]);
```

and assembly code looks

```
002D11D0  vsqrtps     ymm0,ymmword ptr a (202D3380h)[eax]
```

With a line

```
c[i] = 1.0f / sqrtf(a[i]);
```

i have an assembly

```
00E71210  vrsqrtps    ymm1,ymm0  
00E71214  vmulps      ymm0,ymm1,ymm0  
00E71218  vmulps      ymm0,ymm0,ymm1  
00E7121C  vsubps      ymm0,ymm0,ymm6  
00E71220  vmulps      ymm0,ymm0,ymm1  
00E71224  vmulps      ymm0,ymm0,ymm7
```

It is obviously reasonable becouse `vrsqrtps` is much more faster than `vsqrtps`. So in case of reciprocal value of square root its simply faster to call non-accurate function `vrsqrtps` and then do some two iteration to get more precise value.

**And my question is:**
Is it possible to tell the compiler that additional iterations are not nessesary? So the assembly will be without additional multiplications. Error of ~1.5 * 2^-12 is fully sufficient for me, since i want to add thousands of these results where many bits of accuracy will be droped as well. I prefer a way to not inlining some assembly code into C++ code.

(after edit) Compiler comand line:

```
/GS /Qpar /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Ox /Ob2 /sdl /Fd"Release\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:fast /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /arch:AVX2 /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Ot /Fp"Release\performancetest.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

Comment: Maybe you can use some genetic algorithm to derive a short polynomial for you, to give an estimate of 1/sqrt. I think magic numbers can be generated like this. a1+a2*x+a2*x*x +... as many elements as you need. I don't know how fast vrsqrtps than these are.

Comment: which compiler do you use?

Comment: The magic number trick is allready implemented into rsqrt instrunction. Its not wise to write it on my own since this instruction has exactly the same latency and trougthput than one ordinary multiplication i guess. (i use standard Microsoft C++ compiler for Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: "Is it possible to tell the compiler that additional iterations are not nessesary?": I think there isn't. You need to use intrinsics to solve the problem. It is not that hard to do, and you can achieve the same vectorization as the compiler does.

Comment: I was finally able to [reproduce it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vPDLWu) given that you initially didn't provide even the compiler, and then not the flags nor full source code. (You can ignore the aliasing checks and alternative assembly, I was too lazy to figure out how to tell MSVC that the data is both aligned and `__restrict`.) I recommend you to include this information in the future, especially for questions which are highly compiler and flag-specific. Not only will it allow you to avoid possible down votes, but also it will help people help you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8u_k2LIZyo

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid, there are no compiler flags to force reduced precision calculation for the reciprocal square root.

But you can easily write your own function for that using intrinsics, for example:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

float fast_rsqrt( float x ) {
    return _mm_cvtss_f32( _mm_rsqrt_ss( _mm_set_ss( x ) ) );
}
```

This will work on x86-64 platforms in Clang, GCC and MSVC compilers. The latest MSVC will produce such assembly code for it:

```
float fast_rsqrt(float) PROC                                ; fast_rsqrt
        rsqrtss xmm1, xmm0
        movaps  xmm0, xmm1
        ret     0
float fast_rsqrt(float) ENDP                                ; fast_rsqrt
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dE47M6a8x

Comment: The question wants `vrsqrtps ymm`, so you'd actually want to `_mm256_loadu_ps` / `_mm256_rsqrt_ps`.  But yes, manual vectorization is the only way to get mainstream compilers to use `rsqrt` without a Newton iteration.  (Otherwise rsqrt is a lot less valuable, except in loops that just use sqrt, not as part of some large calculation that would keep other execution units busy between sqrt operations.  In that case it's often good to just use `sqrtps` on modern CPUs where it's somewhat pipelined and still only 1 or a couple uops.)